# Docker - Error: dockerfile parse error on line 3: unknown instruction: export

Tags: docker

Okay, after a complete new install of Docker. I am getting an error when trying to do sudo docker-compose build on a Dockerfile.

Error: dockerfile parse error on line 3: unknown instruction: export (did you mean expose?)

```
docker-compose build on the Dockerfile. The error is 
dockerfile parse error on line 3: unknown instruction: export (did you mean expose?)
ERROR: Service 'builder' failed to build : Build failed
```

The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
### Builder (for Frontend) ###

export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
docker build -t myimage .

FROM node:19.3-buster-slim

# Switch to the node_modules install directory (if -g is used)
# So NODE_MODULES env var is set correctly
WORKDIR /usr/local/lib/node_modules

COPY frontend/node-requirements.txt ./node-requirements.txt

RUN echo "unsafe-perm=true" > .npmrc
RUN cat node-requirements.txt | xargs npm install -g

COPY --chmod=0755 .docker/builder/entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

COPY frontend /app
VOLUME /app

ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

Does anyone have any idea on what could be causing this error? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First two commands are bash commands, not part of **Dockerfile**.

Commands to run in terminal:

```bash
$ export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
$ docker build -t myimage .
```

Dockerfile Content:

```
FROM node:19.3-buster-slim

# Switch to the node_modules install directory (if -g is used)
# So NODE_MODULES env var is set correctly
WORKDIR /usr/local/lib/node_modules

COPY frontend/node-requirements.txt ./node-requirements.txt

RUN echo "unsafe-perm=true" > .npmrc
RUN cat node-requirements.txt | xargs npm install -g

COPY --chmod=0755 .docker/builder/entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

COPY frontend /app
VOLUME /app

ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
```